# How to solve "Failed to find provider info for com.my.package.urbanairship.provider"?

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to enable push notifications in my `Android` app with `Urban Airship` and `GCM`. I create an `GCM` account using the instructions given [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and set a development app on `Urban Airship`. Then I copied code from the sample app shown [here](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-samples).

Now when I run my app I get

```
E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.my.package.urbanairship.provider
```

and then

```
E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.my.package.urbanairship.provider
E/XXXX - UALib﹕ Failed to insert in UrbanAirshipProvider.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.my.package.urbanairship.provider/preferences
```

What am I missing?

**app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties**

```
developmentAppKey = <my developmentAppKey>
developmentAppSecret = <my developmentAppSecret>
productionAppKey = 
productionAppSecret = 
gcmSender = <my gcmSender>
inProduction = false
# LogLevel is "VERBOSE", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR" or "ASSERT"
developmentLogLevel = DEBUG
productionLogLevel = ERROR
minSdkVersion = 15
```

**app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.package" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />  <!-- Required for Push -->

    <!-- Urban airship -->

    <permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.UA_DATA" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.UA_DATA" />
    <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application has access to the Urban Airship provider -->

    <!-- GCM -->

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
    <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace PACKAGE_NAME with your package name -->
    <permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->


    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Urban Airship and GCM -->

        <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreActivity"/>

        <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
        <!-- Replace the receiver below with your package and class name -->
        <receiver android:name=".GCMIntentReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.CHANNEL_UPDATED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.DISMISSED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.RECEIVED" />
                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.my.package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED for PlayServiceUtils.handleAnyPlayServicesError to handle Google Play services recoverable errors. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.urbanairship.google.PlayServicesErrorActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship Push. The priority is important to be set lower than the
        application's push intent receiver in order for the push intent receiver to handle push intents
        before the core receiver. This allows the application to launch any activities before Urban
        Airship performs any actions or falls back to launching the application launch intent. -->
        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="-999">
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.my.package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED for GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.my.package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:label="Push Notification Service" />

        <!-- ... -->        

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**app/src/main/java/com/my/package/MyApp**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    /* ... */

    /* Urban Airship */

    UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
            // Perform any airship configurations here
            // Create a customized default notification factory
            DefaultNotificationFactory defaultNotificationFactory = new DefaultNotificationFactory(getApplicationContext());
            defaultNotificationFactory.setSmallIconId(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            defaultNotificationFactory.setColor(NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT);
            // Set it
            airship.getPushManager().setNotificationFactory(defaultNotificationFactory);
            // Enable Push
            airship.getPushManager().setPushEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**app/src/main/java/com/my/package/GCMIntentService**

```
package com.my.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.urbanairship.push.BaseIntentReceiver;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushMessage;


public class GCMIntentReceiver extends BaseIntentReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentReceiver";
    @Override
    protected void onChannelRegistrationSucceeded(Context context, String channelId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Channel registration updated. Channel Id:" + channelId + ".");
        // Broadcast that the channel updated. Used to refresh the channel ID on the main activity.
        //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION_UPDATE_CHANNEL));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onChannelRegistrationFailed(Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Channel registration failed.");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received push notification. Alert: " + message.getAlert() + ". Notification ID: " + notificationId);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onBackgroundPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received background push message: " + message);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationOpened(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "User clicked notification. Alert: " + message.getAlert());
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationActionOpened(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId, String buttonId, boolean isForeground) {
        Log.i(TAG, "User clicked notification button. Button ID: " + buttonId + " Alert: " + message.getAlert());
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNotificationDismissed(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification dismissed. Alert: " + message.getAlert() + ". Notification ID: " + notificationId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a provider defined in your manifest. You should have something like this:

```
<provider
    android:name="provider"
    android:authorities="com.my.package.urbanairship.provider"
    android:exported="false"/>
```